# How can I initialize a std::vector with a size parameter and have each object constructed independently?

Tags: c++

I like creating vectors with a given size and value, for example like this:

```
std::vector<std::string> names(10);
```

However, this a few times this led to unexpected results. For example in the following code each `UniqueNumber` turns out to have the same value:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>


struct UniqueNumber
{
    UniqueNumber() : mValue(sInstanceCount++)
    {
    }

    inline unsigned int value() const
    {
        return mValue;
    }

private:
    static unsigned int sInstanceCount;
    unsigned int mValue;
};


int UniqueNumber::sInstanceCount(0);


int main()
{
    std::vector<UniqueNumber> numbers(10);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < numbers.size(); ++i)
    {
        std::cout << numbers[i].value() << " ";
    }
}
```

Console output:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

It does make sense when looking at std::vector's constructor:

```
explicit vector(size_type __n,
                const value_type& __value = value_type(),
                const allocator_type& __a = allocator_type());
```

Apparently the vector was initialized with copies of the same object.

Is there also a way to have each object default constructed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`generate` or `generate_n` are purpose-designed for just what you want to do.  Here's a complete example:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Foo
{
public:
    Foo() : n_(++water_) {};
    operator unsigned () const { return n_; }
private:
    static unsigned water_;
    unsigned n_;
};

Foo make_foo()
{
    return Foo();
}

unsigned Foo::water_ = 0;

int main()
{
    vector<Foo> v_foo;
    generate_n(back_inserter(v_foo), 10, &make_foo);
    copy(v_foo.begin(), v_foo.end(), ostream_iterator<unsigned>(cout, " "));
}
```

Output: `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10`

Comment: Thanks, for offering a non-intrusive solution.

Comment: @StackedCrooked, actually it is intrusive, I'd prefer using an object for `make_foo`, it would be much better.

Answer (score 4):

Vector is copy-constructing the elements for initialization.

Try that:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>


struct UniqueNumber
{
    UniqueNumber(bool automatic = true) 
        : mValue(automatic?sInstanceCount++:Special)
    { }

    UniqueNumber(UniqueNumber const& other) 
        : mValue(other.mValue==Special?sInstanceCount++:other.mValue)
    { }

    unsigned int value() const
    {
        return mValue;
    }

private:
    static int sInstanceCount;
    unsigned int mValue;
    static unsigned int const Special = ~0U;
};


int UniqueNumber::sInstanceCount(0);


int main()
{
    std::vector<UniqueNumber> numbers(10,UniqueNumber(false));
    for (size_t i = 0; i < numbers.size(); ++i)
    {
        std::cout << numbers[i].value() << " ";
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not sure why you added the additional boolean argument to UniqueNumber's constructor, but clearly, your method is the safest one (compared to other propositions).

Comment: The boolean is so user can construct it unique or special (one that is sort of without value).

Comment: It's creative, but using global variables is bad practice ;)

Comment: @MatthieuM: Where's the global variable?

Comment: @Tomalak: `sInstanceCount` is globally available, across scopes and threads.

Comment: @Matthieu: It's `private` so although it's globally "available", it is not globally *accessible*. Static members aren't usually considered to be "globals".

Answer (score 4):

There are two ways of doing that.

The nice, and C++0x way, is to take advantage of initializers list:

```
std::vector<UniqueNumber> vec = { UniqueNumber(0), UniqueNumber(1) };
```

Obviously the issue here is that you have to specify them out in full.

In C++03, I would simply use a loop:

```
std::vector<UniqueNumber> vec;
vec.reserve(10);
for (size_t i = 0; i != 10; ++i) { vec.push_back(UniqueNumber(i)); }
```

Of course this could perfectly get embedded in a builder function:

```
template <typename ValueType, typename Generator>
std::vector<ValueType> generateVector(size_t size, Generator generator)
{
  std::vector<ValueType> vec;
  vec.reserve(size);
  for (size_t i = 0; i != size; ++i) { vec.push_back(generator()); }
  return vec;
}
```

With NRVO kicking in, it's about the same, and it lets you specify the values created freely.

The same can be achieved with the STL `generate_n` in `<algorithm>`, and I'll include a feel of lambda syntax.

```
std::vector<ValueType> vec;
size_t count = 0;
std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(vec), 10, [&]() { return Foo(++count); });
```

Proposed by `@Eugen` in the comments :)

---

Note: wrt to "surprise", if you wish to have unique elements, perhaps that a `vector` is not the most suitable data structure. And if you actually need a `vector`, I would consider wrapping into a class to ensure, as an invariant, that elements are unique.

Comment: Beat me to it, was about to propose a using `std::generate_n( std::back_inserter( numbers ), 10, ... );` with `...` being is either a "regular" `CreateUniqueNumber` function or a lambda...

Comment: @Eugen: Ah, I thought briefly about having seen such a construct already, but could not remember it was a STL function! Of course the question is always how do get from a simple `for` to a long-winded expression...

Comment: <personal_opinion>I find generate_n more expressive than a generic for and no more long-winded especially with lambdas into play</personal_opinion>

Answer (score 3):

You need to add a copy constructor:

```
UniqueNumber(const UniqueNumber& un) : mValue(sInstanceCount++)
{ }
```

The fill constructor of `std::vector` is not calling your default constructor.  Rather, it's calling the default *copy* constructor which exists implicitly.  That constructor of course will not increment your internal static counter variable.

You also need to define an assignment operator as well.

However, using an object that has an internal static counter with an `std::vector` is going to produce unexpected results, because the vector can internally copy-construct/assign your object as much as it sees fit.  So this may interfere with the copy-semantics you require here.

Comment: Well, it is calling the default constructor once, and then calling the default copy constructor for each element it adds in. The results may still be a little unexpected in that the values will start at 1 and not 0 if you don't notice this.

Comment: That would fix my sample, but now a copy is no longer identical to the original. I think that's rather unintuitive behavior.

Comment: This solution has a problem that when vector fills up and you push_back one more then all the values will change.

Comment: @Öö Tiib that's true.  And really, that's the problem in general with using STL containers with objects whose copy/assign semantics do more than just produce identical clones.